# MVC Debugging tip: Long delay before clientside validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, debugging, submit, client-side

I have an appication wicth a form. When the form is submitted, there is a long delay(about 10-15sec) during which nothing happens: it appears to be frozen and after that, the clientside validation is applied.
Does anyone know of how to debug this? I don't know if it is a script that causes this behavior or some part of the code. Do you have any tips in debugging an application after the submit button is clicked?

Comment: You would have to post your code. For anyone to have any idea of whats going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot watch client-side actions as well as "server-sided" where you have breakpoints.

the only helpful way i can think of is `console.log("message");` in your validation procedure.

developer-tools like firebug and chrome-dev-tools help a lost when examining JS-Errors and networking issues.

you could try timestamping `onClick` and on start validation, even though client-side validation should be executed "instantly".

Comment: Thank you. Chrome-dev tool is helpful. It does show me networking issues